# "Sequence-builder" notation

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, online-resources

I am somewhat familiar with set-builder notation, but I'm wonder what the equivalent notational conventions for sequences are. I know that one can denote a sequence as the following:

$$\{a_n\}_x^y \ \ \text{and} \ \ (a_n)_x^y$$

But what if you want to state something about how that sequence works as well? Consider the sequence of all even numbers from $0$ to $24$. If it was a set, I believe one would write:

$$\{x \in \Bbb N : x = 2n, \  n \in \Bbb N_0^{12}\}$$

Or equivalently:

$$\{x \in \Bbb N : n \in \Bbb N, \ 0 \le x = 2n \le 24 \}$$

How would one write this as a sequence? I'll be dealing with a lot more complex sequences (and sets) than this, so I want to be as fluent in the notation as possible. Are there any free and up-to-date resources that discuss the matter in detail?

Comment: For the set, I'd instead write $\{2n : n \in \mathbb{N}, 0 \le n \le 12\}$; for the sequence, maybe $\{2n\}_{n=0}^{24}$ or $(2n)_{n=0}^{24}$. But I don't know how standard either of these notations are.

Comment: @angryavian A problem with your set notation is that it seems to me that you lose a convential way to refer to the elements. Things like $\forall x \in S$, and $x_1,x_2,...$, or the general $x_i$, would all look weird (IMO) if written as $\forall 2n \in S$, $2n_1, 2n_2,...$, $2n_i$. As for the indexed ones, one might even have to write, to avoid the ambiguity of whether it is the $n$ that's indexed, or the whole thing, $(2n)_1,(2n)_2,...(2n)_i$. I am not an expert in this though (otherwise I wouldn't be asking), so do correct me if I'm wrong on this being unconventional.

Answer (score 2):

$
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
$
A sequence can be seen as a function whose domain is a subset of natural numbers (or integers). This is also how an $n$-tuple is treated.

$$
(x_1, \cdots, x_n) = (x_i)_{i=1}^{n}
$$

Consider the function $f:\{0, 1,\cdots, 12\} \to \Z$ defined by $\forall n \in \{0,1,\dots,12\}: f(n) = 2n$. Then, the sequence can be denoted by $(f_i)_{i=0}^{12}$, or simply $(2i)_{i=0}^{12}$. Therefore, it is natural to define a *function* and use it as a sequence by denoting $f(i) = f_i$.

**Comment**: I believe that your set-builder notation is not standard because the elements are not clear; $x$ or $n$? I would write
$$
\{x \in \Z ~|~ \exists n \in \{0,1,\cdots,12\}: x = 2n\}
$$
or simply
$$
\{2(n-1) ~|~n\in \N \land n \le 13\}
$$

Some authors distinguish $(x_i)$ from $\{x_i\}$; the latter denotes the image (set) of the sequence $(x_i)$, which is exactly what I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not familiar with the $f : \{0,1,...,12\} \rightarrow \Bbb N$. Do you mean it is a subset of $\Bbb N$ that misses no numbers between $0$ and $12$? Also, thanks for the comment. Completely missed the fact that I made it ambiguous whether the elements were $n$ or $x$ by placing them both in front of the colon. I'll fix it.

Comment: @user110391 Yes. It is a roster notation corresponding to $\{n \in \mathbb{Z}~|~0\le n \le 12\}$. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)#Roster_notation

Comment: @user110391 I agree with Hermis14's answer and Comment; also, I've encountered using angle instead of round brackets to denote sequences.